# Handshaking between JBOSS and NGINX load balancer to address time-out issue

Tags: java, nginx, jboss, load-balancing, connection-timeout

As part of our project, we are using JBOSS application server and NGINX load balancer. Currently, there are two application servers configured in the load balancer. Our application is a stateful application. Hence, we are using IP_HASH configuration in NGINX for sticky sessions.

The problem is with PROXY_TIMEOUT. Some of the functionalities, such as exporting the data to excel, are taking 100-150 seconds to process the request and generate the response. However, according to our system administrator, ideal timeout value should be less than 30 seconds to ensure 100% availability of the application, even when a single server is down for maintenance/failure. If we configure such a value, the request that takes more time is getting timedout.

I want to understand whether a configuration exists either in JBOSS or NGINX through which NGINX can differentiate the difference between JBOSS processing the request and JBOSS is down. I am basically looking for a mechanism of communication between JBOSS and NGINX when JBOSS is up and processing the request so that NGINX will not timeout the connection.